# Create and use a class in the same line

Tags: vba

In JavaScript, and other Object oriented languages, you can instantiate a new instance of a class, and use a method of the class instance in the same line. For example:

```
class customClass {
    method(){
        return "hello"
    }
}
var s = (new customClass).method() // s = "hello"
```

If I try the same in VBA:

```
s = (new customClass).method()
```

I get a `Compile error`: `Expected: end of statement`, while highlighting the `.` after `customClass)`.

If you like you can do the following:

```
Dim c as new customClass: s=c.method()
```

however in this case, in my opinion, it is not clear that `s` is being set at all making code more difficult to manage.

Is there an alternative method which makes the line clearer to understand, while still being quick and easy to write?

Comment: Fewer lines of code doesn't mean better readability. If VBA requires more lines to generate readable code, you shouldn't shy away from that.

Comment: JavaScript and "Object Oriented"? Well if you say so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a new instance of a class to the [CallByName Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/callbyname-function) and have it access the method for you.

```
Dim s As String: s = CallByName(New customClass, "method", VbMethod)
```

[image]

Comment: You're correct, this is probably going to be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can.

```
With New Collection: .Add 42: Debug.Print .Count: End With
```

I'd probably want to chew the head off whoever put that in production code, but sure you *can*.

Doesn't mean you *should*.

Note that for some reason you don't get IntelliSense for `With` block variable references in such inline `With` blocks.

May or may not have something to do with *VBA code shouldn't be written like this*.

---

If the method you want to invoke doesn't alter global or instance state, consider specifying a `VB_PredeclaredId` module attribute on your class instead (export the module, edit its header in Notepad, re-import the module).

That way this code becomes legal, and looks much more VBA-idiomatic:

```
SomeCustomClass.SomeMethod
```

The mechanics are identical to those involved when people do `UserForm1.Show` off the default instance, without creating a `New` object.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I have thought of 2 methods of solving the problem.

The first method I came up with is a bit hacky, but it does the trick:

```
s = Array(new someClass)(0).method()
```

However in general this method is quite confusing and difficult to read... So instead I figured you could just use a helper function instead:

```
function proxy(a as variant) as variant
    if isObject(a) then
        set proxy = a
    else
        proxy = a
    end if
end function

sub textProxy()
    s = proxy(new someClass).method()
    debug.print s
end sub
```

It is a shame however that you lose the intelisense in both of these examples... But I guess that's more of a problem with the VBE than the methods themselves.

Comment: You lose IntelliSense in the 2nd example, only because you are returning a `Variant`. Return `SomeClass` and the calling code will get IntelliSense.

Comment: I know why it occurs but, ideally, I wouldn't particularly want hundreds of different proxys for each type of object either...